# Updating a data.frame based on a lookup value

Tags: r

So I've got a very strict system that allows for adding in R scripting to handle some data. It's a front end system and I've got about 1000 characters to throw in as much as I can. What I'm working on doing is replacing the values on a data.frame (filedata_model) with a value from a translation list.

here's what I have so far:

```
vGrades <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 0, 4, 4, 3.7, 3.3, 3, 2.7, 2.3, 2, 1.7, 1.3, 1, 0, 0); 
vGradeMx <- matrix(vGrades, nrow = 14, ncol = 2); 
colnames(vGradeMx) <- c("CB_GRADE", "RNL_GPA"); 
vGradeTb <- as.data.frame(vGradeMx);
```

I get this is probably wildly inefficient. I'm used to working with VBA and C based programming languages and a LOT of SQL.  If I could write an update statement this would take me 2 seconds. But I don't have any kind of back end access, or write capabilities on the actual data itself outside of this small box I can throw R scripting into.

So here's why I've written what I have:
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 - These are the values we're getting back from a research vendor in a file
0, 4, 4, 3.7, 3.3, 3, 2.7, 2.3, 2, 1.7, 1.3, 1, 0, 0 - These are the values that we'd like to change them to.

I set up an additional data frame to hold the original and translation values, but now what? Everything I have tried generally fails.  All the R I've learned has come from a weekend of trying to cram as many books in my brain as I can.

I appreciate the help!

Comment: try to look at the `merge` function

Comment: @BrunoZamengo - Is this going to replace the original value with the translated value, or is this going to add in an additional column to the dataset?  What I'm reading of merge is that it simply joins the tables together. I need it to replace the original values on the original data frame.

Comment: `merge`, which adds columns, then remove the original column. It's analogous to SQL's "join" operators, and can be used in similar ways.

Comment: @r2evans It doesn't look like this is working for me:
`merge(vGradeTb, filedata_model, by.x="CB_GRADE", by.y = "HS_GPA")`
This added the CB_GRADE and RNL_GPA columns from the lookup table, but in no particular order. If I compare the original value of HS_GPA, I'm not seeing the correct value in RNL_GPA that I'd like to see. It looks like it just went straight down the list and spaced everything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
filedata_model$column_name_here <- vGradeTb$RNL_GPA[match(filedata_model$column_name_here, 
                                                          vGradeTb$CB_GRADE)]
```

where `column_name_here` is the column containing the values you want to change.